# Reactive forms and math operations with different inputs in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to develop something really silly, but I am little bit stuck with it.

I have 3 inputs. In the first input, the customer introduces a price; in the second input, the customer chooses an option; and in the third input, load the result.

I'm trying to do it with reactive forms with Angular 5, and I can't set the value on the third input correctly. I let you code here.

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label>Purchase price</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="purchaseprice">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label>Taxes</label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="taxes">
      <option>21%</option>
      <option>10%</option>
      <option>4%</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label>Purchase price + Taxes.</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
           formControlName="pricetaxes">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where are you doing the calculation after selecting first 2 input? show me the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After check the posts that you guys did. i had enough info to solve my problem.

Here i let you with 3 inputs, how the customer can check both prices and calculate it with different taxes.

You can check the Stackblitz demo ->> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atbmpa

Comment: Glad you find a solution that fits your needs. That said, I'd still go for my answer and here's why: First (important) issue --> try to update the purchase price with the up and down arrow on the right of the input (you know it's an input with type number). Then the final result is not updated. Then your methods are assigning the result to a class variable and also returning it. I also prefer to use the power of observable for that kind of things and it's one of the brilliant things with reactive forms.

Comment: Great! thanks for your comments!, i will try to update it with observables and I will try to perfect it!

Answer (score 2):

With Reactive Form, you think that the data of the form are percent and price. The total is not a data. So

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (submit)=submit(myForm)>
  <select class="form-control" name="taxes" formControlName="percent" >
    <option [value]="0">No Discount</option>
    <option [value]="21">21%</option>
       <option [value]="10">10%</option>
       <option [value]="4">4%</option>
  </select>
  <input formControlName="price">
  <!--see that the "total" is NOT a formGroupName. Is a simple input with [value] -->
  <input [value]="(100-myForm.get('percent').value)*myForm.get('price').value/100.0">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
{{myForm?.value |json}}
```

See how we create the data in a submit

```
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){

ngOnInit()
  {
    //See that my form only have "percent" and "price"
    this.myForm=this.fb.group({
      percent:0,
      price:0
    })
  }
  //In the submit function
  submit(myForm:FormGroup)
  {
    if (myForm.valid)
    {
      //we create a object data with all the properties of myForm
      //we're using the spread operator the theee points
      // and the property "total"
      var data={...myForm.value,
                total:(100-myForm.value.percent)*myForm.value.price/100.0};
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the solution in this way, this is the component.html

```
<form #form="ngForm">
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <label>Purchase price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="purchaseForm" [(ngModel)]="model.pprice">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>Taxes</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="taxes" (change)="calculate()"  [(ngModel)]="model.tax">
            <option value="21">21%</option>
            <option value="10">10%</option>
            <option value="4">4%</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <label>Purchase price + Taxes.</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ptax" [(ngModel)]="model.total"> 
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

The change event in the select box will trigger the function to calculate the total, this is the component.ts

```
model = {
    pprice:null,
    tax:null,
    total:null
  }

  calculate(){
    this.model.total = +this.model.pprice + +this.model.tax;
  }
```

This is the sample created

[Code snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mka4xs?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Hello mate! i tried your snippet but is not doing exactly what i want. The "complicated" part of it... is that the option that the customer choose is a percentage... so if the purchase price is 100 and the tax is 21% the total price must be 121.
Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: @SergioCanoSedano i dont do any calculatins to find the precentage, just added the number from select and input box. addition is done on select change event. you can modify it. its just a prototype

Answer (score 0):

TS:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    purchasePrice: new FormControl(''),
    taxes: new FormControl(''),
  });

  get purchasePrice(): number {
    return +this.form.get('purchasePrice').value;
  }

  get taxes(): number {
    return +this.form.get('taxes').value / 100;
  }

  get totalPrice(): number {
    return this.purchasePrice + (this.purchasePrice * this.taxes);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div>
    <label>Purchase price</label>
    <input type="number" formControlName="purchasePrice">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Taxes</label>
    <select formControlName="taxes">
      <option [value]="21">21%</option>
      <option [value]="10">10%</option>
      <option [value]="4">4%</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span [ngClass]="{ 'valid': purchasePrice, 'invalid': !purchasePrice }">Purchase price</span>
    +
    <span [ngClass]="{ 'valid': taxes, 'invalid': !taxes }">Taxes</span>: 

    <ng-container *ngIf="purchasePrice && taxes; else fillTheForm">
      <b>{{ totalPrice }}</b>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #fillTheForm>
      Please fill the form
    </ng-template>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a Stackblitz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohmdj2

Of course you can easily add a submit method like that (added on Stackblitz)

```
  submit() {
    const finalRes = {
      purchasePrice: this.purchasePrice,
      taxes: this.taxes,
      totalPrice: this.totalPrice
    };

    console.log(finalRes)
  }
```

Comment: To... Someone? That'd be nice to know why you downvote when you do :)

Comment: ohh Sorry mate! i loved your answer, even you gave me the idea to solve my problem! here i let you how i solved it and did it easier in my opinion :P

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atbmpa

In my example, you can see the customer can introduce the price in both sides and you have the result. After change the taxes, you can fill it for a new calculation.

Comment: i added my answer too, please check it out and vote if you think is well solved too :) ( sorry but im a little newbie in this world, i forgot to mention that i am a junior developer ^^)

Comment: Hello again... i have been thinking about this problem that i have... and also thinking about your answer... i tried everything and i have some problems that i dont know how to solve. 
Here i let you the stackblitz updated.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atbmpa
I don't know why the [value] doesn't get updated after do the maths...
As you can see in the console. i subscribed to valueChanged to check the 'purchasePriceTaxes' 's value, why the hell doesn't change?...